# Solar Cells Charging a Li-Po Battery

Tags: quadcopter, power

Is there a way to charge a Li-Po battery using solar panels to increase the flight time of a quadcopter during its flight?

Comment: Is there something about this question that is different from the [last time you](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/8852/9720) or [your teammate](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/8906/9720) asked about this?

Comment: Yes because we need to find a way on how to charge the Li-Po battery with the use of solar panels in just a few minutes, we've been checking on booster circuit to help increase the output of the solarpanels but it is still not enough to charge the battery

Comment: What do you mean, "in just a few minutes"? Can you edit your question to include **(1)** battery data, such as: **(1a)** the battery datasheet, **(1b)** nominal voltage, **(1c)** capacity, **(1d)** C rating; **(1e)** battery chemistry; **(2)** solar panel data, such as: **(2a)** solar panel datasheet, **(2b)** solar panel nominal voltage, **(2c)** solar panel nominal current; **(3)** design criteria, such as: **(3a)** desired charging time, **(3b)** starting and ending state of charge limits, **(3c)** schematic showing solar panel - battery arrangement (number of devices, connections, etc.).

Comment: Much more information is required: size of quadcopter, number of motors, current draw of motors, available payload size / weight, available square area of photo cells, what kind of efficiency do you anticipate getting from the photo cells (i.e. what is your latitude, will the cells be oriented to the sun, will it be shady / full sun), and many more...

Comment: @Ben - I was restricting this to just "how do I charge a Li-Po battery using solar panels?" In previous questions (see links above), OP et al. have stated that their intention is to switch between two batteries; one online, powering the quadrotor; one offline, connected to the charging circuit. My comment continues to be, "Is it worth the effort?" - Does the added weight actually net any capacity, but they deflect and reiterate [they're not interested in feasibility.](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/8906/how-do-i-create-a-portable-solar-panel-lipo-charger#comment14690_8906).

Comment: Well, the question clearly indicates a desire to increase flight time of a robot.  I think inferring information from other posts is not the right way to go about it.  If they are not interested in feasibility on a robot, then all their questions should be moved to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I voted to close this question as it is unclear what you're asking - "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need."

Comment: Sorry for the late reply been busy, @chuck this is the battery we are using http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__56839__Multistar_High_Capacity_3S_5200mAh_Multi_Rotor_Lipo_Pack.html

Comment: Our solarpanels are made individually from this http://www.cavite-ecosolutions.com/diy.html see the 3x6 inches, combined in series and parallel connections

Comment: @DaleSebastian - If you add more information (like I specifically asked for above) I'll retract my close vote, but linking to a DIY parts list and saying "they're wired together" is not sufficient to answer clarify anything.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. This is not to say that someone won't extend the flight time of a copter using solar energy one day. But if you attach off the shelf solar panels to off the shelf LiPo batteries and use an off the shelf or quickly fabricated custom power conversion electronics, then the reduction in flight time from the extra mass will be similar to any energy gained from the solar panels.

You can review further discussion on this topic here: [How do I create a portable solar panel lipo charger?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/8906/how-do-i-create-a-portable-solar-panel-lipo-charger)